# Excel 2007: The empty look of a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

How is it that in Excel 2007, an empty pivot table sometimes looks like this:

[image]

and sometimes it looks like this:

[image]

So what's the difference? How can I make it always look like the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By selecting PivotTable Options (from within a pivot table), Display, and checking Classic PivotTable layout:

[image: Classic layout]

Further details [here](http://officehowto.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/how-do-i-revert-back-to-old-pivot-table.html).